# Universal copy & paste (like in Pushbullet)

Tags: gratis, android, clipboard, synchronization

Pushbullet was amazingly copying the contents of the clipboard amongst all devices - now it put the feature behind a paywall - and not a cheap one.

I presume there is either a free alternative or someone is working on it, as I write. In case there is one, please post it.

Answer (score 4):

[Clipbrd](http://www.clipbrd.com/) exactly does that.
[Airdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid)-It's new Clipboard feature can share clipboard content between Android and computer.

Comment: Clipbrd is working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Clipbrd works just like pushbullets universal copy & paste

Comment: And clipbrd has open sourced its client implementation, so I can be more sure they are not eavesdropping on my contents. Basically it is encrypted with a password, but I have not personally looked into the implementation.

Comment: I love Clipbrd easy and free :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

[ClipSync](http://bdwm.be/cs/) apparently does this. Currently it supports Android, PC (which is what I use). He is willing to implement for iPhone if enough donations are made.

Be aware that ClipSync only works across your local network (LAN or WiFi).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Omnipaste](http://omnipasteapp.com/)

With Omnipaste you can move things between devices with the classical copy and paste and you will receive sms and call notifications to your PC or tablet. More than this, you have the ability to act on those notifications like rejecting the call or sending a SMS messages directly from your computer